# How to determine which Windows Communication Foundation Service is using a given port?

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, tcplistener, netstat

Ideally I want to do this inside of C# so I'm including the C# tag.

I have several Window Communication Foundation Services that are running and open up TCP ports (one each) using `System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost`. I have a listing of the port numbers that are being using but I want to use the running service to map from the port number to the executable.

I have tried to use netstat, TCPView, and few other similar tools I've found trying to search this solution but nothing display my process, the closest I can get is the System (PID 4).

All of these are Windows WCF Services, operate as intended, and do show up in netstat and TCPView (by port number) but can only supply the "System" as the process.

The code is being managed by several different departments, so I'm not considering an common interface approach as a valid solution. I do have full admin rights to the machine.

Comment: Ordinarily, netstat does correctly identify the service processes.  Are you sure these are user-mode services and not device drivers?  How are the ports being opened?

Comment: I used a hack where you get the outuput of netstat with process id and then match the process id against the output of "tasklist" which gives out processname and id.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm running a C# Windows Service. I have the service inheriting from System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase and the override OnStart is instantiating a System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost of my library/codebase type and opening it. Some of the projects have the endpoints defined in their app.config and some are in the code from more/less literals in the .cs file which are, for all intents and purposes, impossible to parse out from the compiled version.

Comment: @NareshJois I looked into doing that 2 step process explicitly before posting, but like I mentioned netstat is returning a PID of 4 meaning System. You can use the -b flag to return the process; however, I'm stuck because all the Windows Services are returning System or "Can not obtain ownership information" depending on host OS. I've read up and found Microsoft changed how it's displayed but is the same thing.

Comment: In case it matters, my intended host machine is Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735120.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702588.aspx

Comment: May I ask why you rolled back my edits?  I assure you that, as written, your question won't attract the attention of the people who might know the answer - as written, it sounds as if you're talking about a conventional Windows service which happens to be written in C#, whereas you're actually talking about a Windows Communication Foundation Service, which is a very special case.  It's the WCF that's opening the network port on your behalf (that's why netstat says System) so you need to talk to people familiar with WCF to get an answer.

Comment: The example code I listed in a comment is a WCF service; however, not all our services are WCF services. I'm still researching some, but your above link does give me baseaddresses for a WCF service with a PID that I can use to get to execution path. It does require changing code though (just the .config file) and does not work when opening up a TCPListener explicitly as some departments' code is doing. So especially with you providing a solution for WCF already (which I do **thank you @HarryJohnston** for), I would rather not get another WCF specific answer.

Comment: For non-WCF services, netstat should give you the correct process ID.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why I can't then. For the sake of SO, I'll change the question back to WCF. Then, can you please form your previous comment into an answer so we can provide people with a valid answer. I can also attach my example code to it. I have access to the other code, but have to discuss with other people on how much I can release/show and should probably be another question at that point anyways. Good?

Comment: For what it's worth, the box I'm looking at right now has a custom web service running under IIS, listening on port 8080, and it too is listed as System (PID=4) in the NETSTAT report (Windows Server 2003).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: indeed, a web service is yet another type of service, distinct from a conventional Windows service and presumably not the same thing as a WCF service either.  In the case of a web service, IIS is responsible for listening on the TCP port.

Comment: @InfinitePossiblities: done.  If you can just tell us which system call is used to listen on the TCP port, it should give us enough of a clue to suggest what might be going on, or at least how best to phrase your next question.

Comment: @InfinitePossiblities: I don't know why your edit was rejected, but I don't seem to have any way to undo it.  Please post your example code as a separate answer.

Comment: Sad boosh, I'll repost in the morning. I probably won't have the info I need to ask on the "other" issue until mid next week. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WCF provides a [WMI interface for diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735120.aspx) which you should be able to use in order to associate a WCF service port with a particular process.  In particular the [Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702588.aspx) class looks promising.

(Please feel free to attach your example code here as discussed, or post it as another answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Adding my sample code to @HarryJohnston's answer:

```
String wcfNamespace = String.Format(@"\\{0}\Root\ServiceModel", "MachineName");

ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
connection.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(wcfNamespace, connection);
scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("Select * From Service");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
ManagementObject[] listing = queryCollection.OfType<ManagementObject>().ToArray();

Dictionary<int, int> portToPID = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
{
    //each of services only have one base address in my example
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri(((Array)mo.Properties["BaseAddresses"].Value).GetValue(0).ToString());
    int pid = Int32.Parse(mo.Properties["ProcessId"].Value.ToString());
    portToPID.Add(baseAddress.Port, pid);
}
```

Also requires add this to each service .config, not WMI Client

```
<system.serviceModel>
    …
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true" />
    …
</system.serviceModel>
```